To prove if there exists a linear transformation that takes a high dimensional complex vector to a scalar injectively
Let $z$ be a complex variable on the unit disc centered at the origin and $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ be holomorphic complex-valued functions of $z$.
Suppose through some mapping we map z to the column vector
\begin{bmatrix}
f(z) \\
g(z)
\end{bmatrix}
injectively. That is, the mapping $z \rightarrow [f(z), g(z)]$ is injective and holomorphic.
Then is the following statement true:
There exist complex numbers $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that, $w(z) = c_1f(z) + c_2g(z)$ and the map $z \rightarrow w$ is injective?

At first we note that an injective entire complex analytic function $g:\mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$ necessarily has the form $g(z) = az + b$ for some $a \ne 0$ and $b$. If this is not the case, then $g$ cannot be a polynomial, and, therefore, $g$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$. But then it is not injective. Indeed, let $D = \{z \in \mathbb C: |z| < 1\}$ and $U =  \{z \in \mathbb C: |z| > 1\}$. Clearly, $g(D)$ and $g(U)$ are open and $g(U)$ is dense in $\mathbb C$ due to to Weierstrass-Casorati theorem. Thus, $g(U)$ intersects $g(D)$, which contradicts injectivity of $g$.
Now consider $f(z) = e^z$ and $g(z) = e^{iz}$. It is easy to see that $f(z) = f(z')$ if and only if $z - z' \in 2\pi i \mathbb Z$ and $g(z) = g(z')$ if and only if $z - z'\in 2\pi \mathbb Z$. Thus, if $f(z) = f(z')$ and $g(z) = g(z')$, then $z = z'$. So the mapping $\mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C^2$ given by $z \rightarrow (f(z), g(z))$ is injective. However, a linear combination $c_1 f + c_2 g$ cannot be equal to a linear function $az + b$ with $a \ne 0$, so it is not injective for all $c_1, c_2$.
Edit. The answer for the functions on the disc $D$ is also no (we use the sets $D$ and $U$ as defined above). We can replace $D$ with the cut complex plane $P = \mathbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0]$, since they are biholomorphically equivalent. Consider $f(z) = e^{1/z^2}$ and let $g(z) = zf(z)$ -- holomorphic functions on $P$. Clearly, if $f(z) = f(z')$ and $g(z) = g(z')$, then $z = g(z)/f(z) = g(z')/f(z') = z'$, so the mapping $z \rightarrow (f(z), g(z))$ is injective. Now, any nontrivial linear combination $h = c_1 f + c_2 g$ has an essential singularity at $z = 0$, so $h(D \cap P)$ is dense in $\mathbb C$ (removing the negative real axis does not affect the statement of Weierstrass-Casorati theorem, since $h$ is an open map) and $h(U \cap P)$ is open. Thus, $h(D \cap P)$ intersects $h(U \cap P)$, so $h$ is not injective.

After reading your answer I realized that I missed a crucial detail in my question. Which is that z lies in the open unit disc centered at the origin. Should I edit the question or would the right way be to open another question?

@AtharvaAalok I think it is simpler to edit the question, and, if I succeed to answer it, I shall edit the answer.

I've edited the question. Please have a look.

I have added the answer. @AtharvaAalok

Thank you for the update. With each answer I am realizing more conditions that I can place on the problem. I think for adding another condition I will first accept this answer of yours and then open up a new problem.

You can find the new question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4997127/to-find-if-there-exists-a-linear-transformation-that-takes-a-high-dim-complex-ve
