To find if there exists a linear transformation that takes a high dim complex vector with no singularities to a scalar injectively on the unit disc
Let $z$ be a complex variable on the unit disc centered at the origin and $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ be holomorphic complex-valued functions of $z$. Also they do not have singularities inside/on the unit disc.
Suppose through some mapping we map z to the column vector
\begin{bmatrix}
f(z) \\
g(z)
\end{bmatrix}
injectively. That is, the mapping $z \rightarrow [f(z), g(z)]$ is injective and holomorphic.
Then is the following statement true:
There exist complex numbers $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that, $w(z) = c_1f(z) + c_2g(z)$ and the map $z \rightarrow w$ is injective?

Note:  this other question doesn't specify on the unit disc

it is very easy to see that a function with a pole of order $3$ or higher on the unit circle cannot be injective nearby in the unit disc, so just take $f(z)=\frac{1}{(1-z)^4}, g(z)=\frac{z}{(1-z)^4}$ and immediately the vector function is injective while any linear combination of $f,g$ is either $0$ or has a pole of order at least $3$ at $1$ so cannot be injective; note that if $f$ nonzero, clearly $f$ injective iff $1/f$ is so, one can use $(1-z)^4, z(1-z)^4$ too and argue similarly now with high order zeroes at $1$

@J.W.Tanner Yeah I asked that question as well. But since I modified it after an answer was made. I have opened up a new question with additional conditions.

@Conrad I have edited the question to include the condition that f and g do not have singularities inside/on the unit disc.

then the $(1-z)^4, z(1-z)^4$ counterexample works
